How can I go directly to the previous line with Point History
I use Point History
, and it works great, if I use the interactive menu interface (point-history-show)
, but it doesn't work, if I try to go one step back directly, using (point-history-prev-line)
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  get-buffer(nil)
  point-history-preview-at-point()
  point-history-prev-line()
  funcall-interactively(point-history-prev-line)
  command-execute(point-history-prev-line record)
  helm-M-x-execute-command(point-history-prev-line)
  helm-execute-selection-action-1()
  helm-execute-selection-action()
  helm-internal((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x72e52704f9e0109>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (100663328 . helm-next-source) (backtab . helm-previous-line) (tab . helm-next-line) (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b0ee80>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b6de80>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b7ce80>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b23e80>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b32e80>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bf1e80>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4be0e80>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bc7e80>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bd6e80>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bb5e80>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4ba4e80>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4c2be80>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . helm-select-action) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_18> helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xd1af032e34a4a30>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ad0b457934ba4b>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (100663328 . helm-next-source) (backtab . helm-previous-line) (tab . helm-next-line) (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b0ee80>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b6de80>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b7ce80>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b23e80>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b32e80>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bf1e80>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4be0e80>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bc7e80>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bd6e80>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bb5e80>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4ba4e80>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4c2be80>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . helm-select-action) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_18> helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1a67ba7ae660caa6>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history)
  helm((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x72e52704f9e0109>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (100663328 . helm-next-source) (backtab . helm-previous-line) (tab . helm-next-line) (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b0ee80>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b6de80>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b7ce80>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b23e80>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b32e80>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bf1e80>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4be0e80>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bc7e80>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bd6e80>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bb5e80>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4ba4e80>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4c2be80>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . helm-select-action) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_18> helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xd1af032e34a4a30>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ad0b457934ba4b>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (100663328 . helm-next-source) (backtab . helm-previous-line) (tab . helm-next-line) (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b0ee80>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b6de80>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b7ce80>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b23e80>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b32e80>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bf1e80>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4be0e80>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bc7e80>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bd6e80>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bb5e80>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4ba4e80>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4c2be80>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . helm-select-action) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_18> helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1a67ba7ae660caa6>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history)
  helm(:sources (((name . "Emacs Commands history") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x72e52704f9e0109>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (100663328 . helm-next-source) (backtab . helm-previous-line) (tab . helm-next-line) (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b0ee80>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b6de80>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b7ce80>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b23e80>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b32e80>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bf1e80>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4be0e80>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bc7e80>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bd6e80>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bb5e80>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4ba4e80>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4c2be80>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . helm-select-action) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_18> helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xd1af032e34a4a30>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (init #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1ad0b457934ba4b>)) (candidates . helm-candidates-in-buffer) (cleanup . helm-M-x--unwind-forms) (keymap keymap (keymap ...) keymap (29 . helm-M-x-toggle-short-doc) (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (27 keymap ...) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (100663328 . helm-next-source) (backtab . helm-previous-line) (tab . helm-next-line) (f12 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b0ee80>)) (f11 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b6de80>)) (f10 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b7ce80>)) (f9 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b23e80>)) (f8 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4b32e80>)) (f7 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bf1e80>)) (f6 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4be0e80>)) (f5 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bc7e80>)) (f4 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bd6e80>)) (f3 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4bb5e80>)) (f2 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4ba4e80>)) (menu-bar keymap ...) (help keymap ...) (23 . helm-helm-yank-text-at-point-with-subkeys) (f1 . #f(compiled-function () ... #<bytecode 0x198018b4c2be80>)) (8 keymap ... ... ... ... ... ...) (20 . helm-toggle-resplit-and-swap-windows) (C-tab . helm-select-action) (67108897 . helm-toggle-suspend-update) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_18> helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match identity) (fuzzy-match . t) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . #("C-j: Describe this command (keep..." 0 3 ...)) (resume . helm-M-x-resume-fn) (multimatch . t) (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (data . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1a67ba7ae660caa6>)) (get-line . buffer-substring-no-properties) (search helm-mm-exact-search helm-mm-search helm-candidates-in-buffer-search-default-fn helm-fuzzy-search))) :prompt "M-x " :buffer "*helm M-x*" :history helm-M-x-input-history :truncate-lines t)
  helm-M-x-read-extended-command([zls lsp-erlang-ls-server-start-fun vc-src-responsible-p vls-tramp nexti lsp-pwsh-help-completion jsonrpc-name zls-tramp lsp-xmlls-tramp-after-open-hook vc-sccs-log-view-mode-hook :maxLength vdiff-hydra lsp-rust-analyzer-injected-modifier-face escape-char w3m-create-image-page soap-operation-namespace-tag hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all erc-toggle-timestamps speedbar-file-regexp eslint-tramp erc-stamp-mode transient:sharper-transient-test:--configuration= erc-networks--warn-on-connect w3m-form-textarea-file-cleanup treemacs--button-symbol-switch erc-server-connect soap-port-type-p kotlin-language-server lsp-java-completion-lazy-resolve-text-edit-enabled request-response-p--cmacro c-list-found-types w3m-session-select-quit lsp-elixir-suggest-specs xref--push-markers helm-highlight-bookmark Noto\ Sans\ Lao\ Looped Above lsp-pyls-plugins-flake8-hang-closing lsp-pylsp-plugins-rope-completion-enabled Man-arguments lsp-typescript-format-insert-space-after-opening-and-before-closing-nonempty-brackets lsp-lua-hint-enable lsp-headerline--face-for-symbol :kill-buffer copy-soap-xs-attribute-group jiralib-fields-for-action-cache-p core-accessing-symbol lsp-rust-analyzer-trait-modifier bibtex-text-in-string zot ...])
  helm-M-x(nil)
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)



Probably a bug. Report it at the Github site.

What @NickD said. And your question (and bug report) should specify the behavior when starting with emacs -Q (no init file). E.g., don't show a backtrace that includes stuff from packages you've loaded.

The software is unmaintained: https://github.com/blue0513/point-history/issues/19

@JasonHunter actually, the software seems "maintained but not developed". The issue you referred to has an owner's comment that they will review and merge fixes that someone comes up with. It's just that the owner won't debug issues/write code themselves. So if you feel motivated, you can fix the problem yourself and the fix should get merged.

My skill level is not on the level to be able to debug this (yet). I will have to look for another package.
